# Why does my mac say up to date with Mojave 10.14.3 and the latest OS is 10.14.4?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook

My Macbook is early 2015 and it was in High Sierra 10.13.6 before upgrading to Mojave.

My first question is:  I think my Macbook is eligible for upgrading to Mojave (and it didn't complain later when I manually installed Majave), but why isn't the Mojave update available to my macbook in App store---the Mojave is not displayed as a candidate in App Store Update?

I followed this link (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201475) and manually downloaded Mojave from App Store.  After installation, I found my mac is in Mojave 10.14.3 instead of the latest 10.14.4.  I wonder why App Store didn't download the latest Mojave?

Then when I check software update by going to System Preferences->Software Update, it says "Your Mac is up to date--macOS Mojave 10.14.3", even though the latest available is 10.14.4.  I wonder why the latest is not available to my machine?

I didn't see obvious issues with Mojave 10.14.3 so far.  Shall I manually download 10.14.4 and upgrade to 10.14.4?

Answer (score 1):

Just some background first...

There is a difference in what Apple calls an **Update** & an **Upgrade**.

Between major versions, eg 10.13.x to 10.14.x you **Upgrade**.
This will be seen at the top of the App Store main page whenever you have the opportunity.

Until 10.15 is released, everything in between is an **Update**.

Updates are no longer in the App Store, they are in System Preferences > Software Update.
Open the panel & it will perform a check.

[image]

If you have it set to automatically check, it will Badge the System Prefs with a red dot in the Dock whenever there is an update waiting.

[image]

If the process has become 'stuck' for any reason, then usually the way to shake it loose is to get the latest **Combo Update** directly from Apple.
Google can always find these very easily from 'combo update 10.14' etc. The current 10.14.4 is at Apple KB - [Download macOS Mojave 10.14.4 Combo Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1996)

Combo updates can be used on any major version to bring it up to date. The normal updater is known as a Delta & can only be used on the previous version.
One advantage of this is it can find & correct many issues that the delta alone cannot.

Comment: So MacOS version of cumulative updates?

Comment: @Ramhound - I guess so - it can go from 10.14.0 or 1, 2, 3 to 10.14.4 [or 5, 6, whatever is current] in a single installer package. This has been standard for many years, though I couldn't say when it started - over a decade ago, at least. It used to be the way to perform a 'bit of a tidy up' at update too, rather than using each delta.